# If joe is out of town, he hasn't heard the news

Tags: subjunctives

The Little, Brown Handbook 9th ed section 14i has

> Not all clauses beginning with 'if' express conditions contrary to
> fact. In the sentence "If Joe is out of town, he hasn't heard the
> news," the verb "is" is correct because the clause refers to a
> condition presumed to exist.

I think the example sentence means "Thanks to Joe staying at home, he then heard the news; he didn't miss the news."

I feel the example sentence is talking about a situation contrary to the fact. Therefore I feel the sentence should be "If Joe were out of town, ..."

Why does the book say the sentence is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misinterpret the sentence. It supposes that the speaker has just heard that Joe **is** out of town and therefore cannot have heard the news.

To express the meaning you suggest, the sentence would have to be

> If Joe had been out of town, he wouldn't have heard the news.

Comment: O I got you. We don't know if we need to tell Joe the news, and someone says he's out of town. Then I say if he's out of town, he doesn't know yet.